# JQuery not working in Wordpress when adding widget code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have my website www.dailycrazydeals.com with all the jquery working properly. But the problem comes when I try to add a recycling widget through the text widget on wordpress.All my other jquery plugins stop working. The code for the recycling widget is as follows:

```
<!-- BEGIN 1-800-RECYCLING.COM WIDGET --> <div id="recycling-widget"></div> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1800recycling.com/recycling-widget/?v=2.0&width=300&height=450&btncolor=fbfbfb"></script> <script type="text/javascript">oerjQuery("#recycling-widget").RecyclingWidget("recycling");</script> <!-- END 1-800-RECYCLING.COM WIDGET -->
```

Please help me solve this problem.Please ask me if you require any other information.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` from the widget code and it should work if you already have jQuery on your site.

See browser console for more details on what's causing the error. But it's probably the fact that you're loading two different jQuery files.

Comment: I tried that but it no longer displays whatever is required. You see, that code is what I got an external website to disply their widgets.I think changing their code doesnt work.I am using jquery 1.9.1 here.

Comment: what does the browser console say? What errors do you get ?

Comment: can you please check it on the above address?theres lot of errors.

Comment: Wow you've got lots JS files on the site.... try adding the code to a separate html file... upload that to your server and add it via iframe to your template. Just make a file with the widget code in it and add an iframe to it.

Comment: that seems like a very difficult task.Can you guide me or is there any solution just to make the widget work?

Comment: Make a html file. Paste the widget code in the file. Upload the file to your server. Instead of the code of the widget add and iframe that has the src the path to the file you created. Save your template or what ever and test.

Comment: how to add the iframe of the html file?